# Parsing this JSON in HIVE

Tags: json, hadoop, hive

I'm completely new to JSON. I have below JSON in one of the HIVE columns. I am not sure, how to arrange {} and [] ,but tried my best.

```
{
  "main_key":
  [
    {
       "type":"RESPONSIBLE",
       "lastName":"John"
    },
    {
       "ids":
       [
         {
            "id":"001815015",
            "qual":"PIN"
          },
          {
            "id":"592852900",
            "qual":"TIN"
          }
        ],
            "type":"BILLING",
            "lastName":"Joe"
    },
    {
        "ids":
        [
                {
                    "id":"002329056",
                    "qual":"PIN"
                }
        ],
                    "type":"SVC",
                    "lastName":"Jame"
    }
    ]
}
```

Above JSON should be parsed to as below. Need Hive query which can do like this.

[image]
Thanks,

Comment: how did you create your table ? have you used JSONserde ? please post your create command.

Comment: I didn't create table, I am yet to create it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_json_object` or `json_tuple`

Example: src_json table is a single column (json), single row table:

```
+----+
                               json
+----+
{"store":
  {"fruit":\[{"weight":8,"type":"apple"},{"weight":9,"type":"pear"}],
   "bicycle":{"price":19.95,"color":"red"}
  },
 "email":"amy@only_for_json_udf_test.net",
 "owner":"amy"
}
+----+



hive> SELECT get_json_object(src_json.json, '$.owner') as owner FROM src_json;
amy
 
hive> SELECT get_json_object(src_json.json, '$.store.fruit\[0]')  as fruitdata FROM src_json;
{"weight":8,"type":"apple"}
 
hive> SELECT get_json_object(src_json.json, '$.non_exist_key') FROM src_json;
NULL
```

[more info](http://thornydev.blogspot.com/2013/07/querying-json-records-via-hive.html)

Answer (score 0):

I got this done by using get_json_object on each and every key.  Thanks~

Comment: Can you share your query?